# A rollercoaster contains four cars, each with six seats. Four families, each containing six individuals wish to ride ...

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> A rollercoaster contains four cars, each with six seats. Four families, each containing six individuals wish to ride the rollercoaster together. In how many ways can the rollercoaster be “loaded” with the individuals so that two individuals ride in the same car if and only if they belong to the same family?

My work: I am thinking about 4*3*2*1 = 24 ways, but I don't know if that's correct.

The question is really saying that each family needs to stay together. There are four cars in the rollercoaster, so the first car will have four families, second car will have three, third car will have two, fourth car will have one.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I am thinking about 4*3*2*1 = 24 ways

Comment: I don't know if that's correct.

Comment: The question is really saying that each family needs to stay together. There are four cars in the rollercoaster, so the first car will have four families, second car will have three, third car will have two, fourth car will have one.

Comment: I do not know if this is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already pointed out, we assign each family to one of the four cars in $4!$ ways. Now, for each car we can arrange the six family members in the six seats in $6!$ ways. Therefore the rollercoaster can be “loaded” in 
$$4!\cdot (6!)^4.$$

Comment: Thank you very much!